# Undefined offset: 0 (View: path\profile.blade.php) issue in laravel

Tags: laravel

When i click form submit button page redirects to addshortlist function. Function showing Undefined offset: 0 (View: path\profile.blade.php ) error. And below my form

```
<form action="addshortlist" id="addshortlist" method="PUT">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
 <input type="hidden" name="shortlistid" value="{{$data[0]->id}}">         
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Shortlist</button>
</form>
```

my route function is

```
Route::post('addshortlist','UserController@addshortlist');
```

function be like

```
function addshortlist()
    { 
       //
    }
```

Comment: Can you `dd($data)` and check if it is an array?

Comment: yes it is array only

Comment: Can you just edit your question and post the output here?

Comment: also, would like to see your edit functions return statement.

Comment: because your $data is an empty array

Comment: i have checked many times, $data contains value only.

Answer (score 0):

Do you include $data array to view returned by `addshortlist()` function?
Like

```
public function addShortList() {
    return view('profile')->with('data', $someDataArray);
}
```

or

```
public function addShortList() {
    return view('profile', compact($someDataArray);
}
```